# Exercise in Hilbert space: Prove $\;φ \in L^1(0,1)\;$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

> Let $\;H=L^2(0,1)\;$ and consider $\;φ(t)= e^{-at} \int_{0}^{t} e^{as}
>  f(s) \;ds\;$ where $\;a\in \mathbb R\;$ and $\;f \in H\;$. Prove that
>   $\;φ \in L^1(0,1)\;$

**My attempt:**

It is sufficient to show: $\; \int_{0}^{1} \vert φ(t) \vert dt \lt \infty\;$.
$\; \vert φ(t) \vert = \vert e^{-at} \int_{0}^{t} e^{as}
 f(s) \;ds \vert \le e^{-at}  \int_{0}^{t} e^{as} 
 \vert f(s) \vert \;ds\; \le e^{-at} (\int_{0}^{t} (e^{as})^2 \; ds)^{1/2} (\int_{0}^{t}
 {\vert f(s) \vert}^2 \;ds)^{1/2}= e^{-at} (\frac{e^{2at} -1}{2a})^{1/2}(\int_{0}^{t}
 {\vert f(s) \vert}^2 \;ds)^{1/2}\; $

At this point I've been stuck. I don't know how to proceed. I believe I should  have had somehow this $\;(\int_{0}^{1} {\vert f(s) \vert}^2 \;ds)^{1/2}\;$ instead of this $\;(\int_{0}^{t} {\vert f(s) \vert}^2 \;ds)^{1/2}\;$ in order to use $\;f \in H\;$ but I can't come up with any good ideas.

Any help would be valuable. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I believe that $t \le 1$. Doesn't this give you what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$e^{-at} (\frac{e^{2at} -1}{2a})^{1/2}$ is bounded on $[0,1]$ and

$(\int_{0}^{t}{\vert f(s) \vert}^2 \;ds)^{1/2} \le (\int_{0}^{1}{\vert f(s) \vert}^2 \;ds)^{1/2}=||f||_2$  for $t \in [0,1]$.